# Wget from webpage in html to many text files

Tags: bash, wget

To download all the page one level below superSite.com I do:

```
wget -r -l1 http:/superSite.com
```

But these pages are saved in the `.html` format. How can I have them be saved 
in `.txt` format? (I need to parse part of the numerical contents of these pages, so I don't care about losing the banners/images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to parse your downloaded HTML files, you can filter them through something like `html2text` (you have to install the package 'html2text').

This might be helpful if you want to get rid of the formatting in the `.html` documents, however, parsing the original `.html` or the new `.txt` files is pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I am asking a second question about this now!

Answer (score 1):

`.html` files *are* text files. The file extension makes absolutely no difference.
All files contain some form of binary in the end, and many files contain text in the end. HTML files are simply composed of the HTML markup as text, which is then parsed by the browser to show what the HTML describes.

If you want to view it as text, use a dedicated text editor and open the HTML files. Or, from your file browser, select "Open as", "Open with", or similar.